# Conflicting multi-line underbrace labels

Tags: math-mode, labels, braces

Sometimes a \makebox gives nice underbrace, sometimes multiline version with \parbox works. But how to combine two multiline-underbrace-equation-labels side by side and make them look good?

```
\documentclass[15pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}       
\usepackage{enumitem}   

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
        MR &\stackrel{!}{=} MC \\
        &\Leftrightarrow \underbrace{\overline{p}_x = \frac{r}{1-\alpha}}_{\text{\makebox[0pt]{MR from production of intermediate good} } } \stackrel{!}{=} \underbrace{\frac{\partial Y}{\partial K} = (1-\alpha) \cdot \frac{Y}{K}}_{\text{\parbox{15em}{marg. rental cost (opp. costs!) due \\ to perfect competition on \underline{goods market}}}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Just using two \parbox and adjust their size to the formular does not look good! There's resulting 3-4 linebreaks. I hope to get the text in maximum two lines.

(1) makebox gives nice spread under the formula
(2) parbox enables multiline text

How to combine both features?

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try `\parbox{0.3\linewidth}{<content>}` for both and remove the forced linebreak `\\\`.

Comment: The solutions with 2 \parboxes spreads the formula very much. I then can read the labels but the math looks horrible :/

Comment: Try the mathtools command `\clap` in the form `\clap{\footnotesize\parbox{0.2\linewidth}{<content>}}`

Comment: :( unfortunately I did not manage to load mathtools yet .. some people recommended it. Don't know how to install it manually (TexnicCenter doesn't do it on its own).

Comment: Mathtools now working, each single text looks nice with \clap{\footnotesize\parbox{0.3\linewidth} ... but those text boxes are still overlapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you hide the widths then you get over-printing without warning. I'm not sure it really works to have so much text in an underbrace, but a couple of suggestions:

[image]

```
\documentclass[15pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}       
\usepackage{enumitem}   

\begin{document}

this
\begin{align*}
        MR &\stackrel{!}{=} MC \\
        &\Leftrightarrow 
\underbrace{\overline{p}_x = \frac{r}{1-\alpha}}_{\text{\shortstack{MR from\\ production of\\ intermediate good}}}
\stackrel{!}{=} 
\underbrace{\frac{\partial Y}{\partial K} = (1-\alpha) \cdot \frac{Y}{K}}_{\text{\shortstack{marg. rental cost\\ (opp. costs!)\\ due to perfect\\ competition on \underline{goods market}}}}
\end{align*}

or this
\begin{align*}
        MR &\stackrel{!}{=} MC \\
        &\Leftrightarrow 
\underbrace{\overline{p}_x = \frac{r}{1-\alpha}}_{\dagger}
\stackrel{!}{=} 
\underbrace{\frac{\partial Y}{\partial K} = (1-\alpha) \cdot \frac{Y}{K}}_{\ddagger}
\end{align*}

$\dagger$: $MR$ from production of intermediate good.

$\ddagger$: Marg. rental cost (opp. costs!) due to perfect competition on \underline{goods market}


\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the difference between `\shortstack` and `\substack`?

Comment: @Manuel hort isn't ub ? `\shortstack` is defined in the latex format  and is text `\substack` is defined in amsmath and is math. Same as difference between `array` and `tabular`.

Comment: Maybe the workaround with placeholders is best :)